# how do i split this string into two starting from a specific position

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this string:

`var str=' "123","bankole","wale","","","","xxx" ';`

I need to split this string into two. The split should start from the last comma. Resulting in:

`' "123", "bankole","wale","","","" '` and  `' "xxx" '`

I used the below to get the `"xxx"`:

`str.split(/[,]+/).pop();  \\""`

however note that the last "" can also be "something"

Comment: Not really clear what problem your trying to explain, but you don't really need the regex here if you just splitting on a comma.  `str.split(",").pop();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achive this.

You could split your string on commas with [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), then get the last element of the created array with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Then [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements left in the first part back into a string.

```js
var str = '"123", "bankole","wale","","","" and  ""';
var arr = str.split(',')
var start = arr.slice(0, -1).join(',')
var end = arr[arr.length-1];

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

In the above code, the part that extracts the last part after the last comma is `arr.slice(0, -1)`. `-1` means start looking from the end of the array and go back 1.
So if you need to split from the second last, use `arr.slice(0, -2)`

```js
var str = '"123", "bankole","wale","","","" and  ""';
var arr = str.split(',')
var start = arr.slice(0, -2).join(',')
var end = arr.slice(-2).join(',')

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

Comment: what if the the split should start from second or third to the last...any idea bro.

Comment: I added another example to help you out.

Comment: elegant. thumbs up

Comment: You should try making this into a function that takes 2 arguments: the array and the position of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `String.prototpye.lastIndexOf()` and `String.prototpye.substring()`

```js
    var str='"123","bankole","wale","","","","something"';
    var lastCommaIndex = str.lastIndexOf(',');
    var part1 = str.substring(0, lastCommaIndex);
    var part2 = str.substring(lastCommaIndex + 1, str.length);
    
    console.log(part1)
    console.log(part2)
```

Comment: what if the the split should start from second or third to the last...any idea bro..

Comment: @Seybanks That's another question. You already have a possible working answer, so I recommend you to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your regex is already what you're looking for, and that you're simply looking to extract the final segment. This can be done with `array_name[array_name.length - 1]`, as can be seen in the following:

```js
var str = ' "123","bankole","wale","","","","something" ';
var parts = str.split(/[,]+/);
console.log(parts[parts.length - 1]);
```

If you also want to remove the quotes, you can run `.replace(/['"]+/g, '')` on the extracted string, as is seen in the following:

```js
var str = ' "123","bankole","wale","","","","something" ';
var parts = str.split(/[,]+/);
var extracted = parts[parts.length - 1];
console.log(extracted.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: it only extracts "" and but not the other parts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as follows.

```js
var str = ' "123","bankole","wale","","","","something" ';
var splitResult = str.split(/,(?!.*,)/);
console.log(splitResult[0])
console.log(splitResult[1])
```